# Many to Many Core Data My Example

Tags: ios, core-data

I am very new to many to many relationships in Core Data and to learn it i've created a example many to many relationship as shown in the diagram below.

The code below shows how the data is populated and retrieved. I would be very thankful if someone could tell me whether this is the correct way of implementing a many to many relationship.

[image]

```
// First Course object
    Course *first = (Course *) [NSEntityDescription
                                insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Course"
                                inManagedObjectContext:[self managedObjectContext]];
    first.title = @"Core Data for iOS and OS X";
    first.releaseDate = [dateFormatter dateFromString:@"16 Oct 2012"];

    // Second Course object
    Course *second = (Course *) [NSEntityDescription
                                 insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Course"
                                 inManagedObjectContext:[self managedObjectContext]];
    second.title = @"C/C++ Essential Training";
    second.releaseDate = [dateFormatter dateFromString:@"26 Jun 2012"];

    // Third Course object
    Course *third = (Course *) [NSEntityDescription
                                insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Course"
                                inManagedObjectContext:[self managedObjectContext]];
    third.title = @"Java Essential Training";
    third.releaseDate = [dateFormatter dateFromString:@"14 December 2011"];

    // Fourth Course object
    Course *fourth = (Course *) [NSEntityDescription
                                 insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Course"
                                 inManagedObjectContext:[self managedObjectContext]];
    fourth.title = @"iOS SDK: Building Apps with MapKit and Core Location";
    fourth.releaseDate = [dateFormatter dateFromString:@"3 August 2012"];

    // Fifth Course object
    Course *fifth = (Course *) [NSEntityDescription
                                insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Course"
                                inManagedObjectContext:[self managedObjectContext]];
    fifth.title = @"Cocoa Essential Training";
    fifth.releaseDate = [dateFormatter dateFromString:@"1 August 2012"];


    // First Lecturer object
    Lecturer *author = (Lecturer *) [NSEntityDescription
                                insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Lecturer"
                                inManagedObjectContext:[self managedObjectContext]];
    author.name = @"Smith";
    [author addCoursesObject:first];
    [author addCoursesObject:second];
    [author addCoursesObject:third];

    // Second Lecturer object
    Lecturer *author2 = (Lecturer *) [NSEntityDescription
                                 insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Lecturer"
                                 inManagedObjectContext:[self managedObjectContext]];
    author2.name = @"John";
    [author2 addCoursesObject:first];
    [author2 addCoursesObject:third];
    [author2 addCoursesObject:fourth];
    [author2 addCoursesObject:fifth];
```

This is how i fetch all the courses that a particular lecturer teaches.

```
  NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SUBQUERY(lecturers, $c, $c.name == 'John').@count > 0"];
        [fetchRequest setPredicate:predicate];

        NSError *error = nil;
        NSArray *fetchedObjects = [[self managedObjectContext] executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];
        if (fetchedObjects == nil)
        {
            NSLog(@"Problem! %@",error);
        }
        NSLog(@"fetch object count %d", [fetchedObjects count]);
        for (Course *c in fetchedObjects)
        {
            NSLog(@" %@", c.title);
        }
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code looks correct, but the predicate

```
 [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SUBQUERY(lecturers, $c, $c.name == 'John').@count > 0"]
```

is too complicated. You don't need a SUBQUERY here. To fetch all courses
that are related to a lecturer with a given name, you can use

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"ANY lectures.name == 'John'"]
```

or better

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"ANY lectures.name == %@", @"John"]
```

because this works even if the name contains any special characters
such as quotation marks.

---

To your question if you need an intermediate table or not:

- Your model is valid and you should use it if it works for you (actually Core Data creates an intermediate SQLite table internally).
- One reason to use an intermediate table

  ```
   Course <-->>CourseLecturer<<-> Lecturer
  ```

  is that you can keep the courses of a lecturer (and the lecturers of a course) in a specified order by adding a sort key to the middle entity.
- Another reason for an intermediate entity is that it makes it possible
  to display a table with all courses and lecturers, with one section for
  each course.

Comment: Is it okay not to use a intermediary table to construct the many to many relationship ?

Comment: so does core data manage the mapping between courses and lecture ? I am asking because i only did  [author2 addCoursesObject:first]; and never  did something like [first addLecture:author2]; ?

Comment: @crowso: Yes. Inverse relationships are automatically updated, it is sufficient to establish one direction.